# RubyMine 5.4 - stable enough?

Tags: ide, rubymine

A small team in our company will likely to be involved in Ruby related development.

We think of using the latest version of RubyMine (5.4) and wonder if it is stable enough or should we stick with the previous (4) version. 
I mean the question really is - are we likely going to hit serious bugs/problems that have not been yet addressed? And is the KB already extensive  enough for this version?

Also having played a bit with this IDE I noticed that it is painfully slow – it is based on a VM with Win7 and other IDEs (e.g. Visual Studio 2012) fly on it. 
What's your experience with RubyMine/VM/Win environment?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RubyMine 5.4 is considered the stable release version and you should not have major problems with it. Note that RubyMine 6 will be released soon and will become the new stable version. License includes a year of free upgrades, so it will cover 6.x and most likely even 7.x versions.

If you have performance issues, refer to [this document](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1144).

Comment: Thanks. Turned out we cannot use RubyMine anyway because all our development is done on VMs. RM support told us that this is the main reason our instances of RM are so slow, pretty much unusable. This cannot be fixed. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @tom33pr you just need to have a local copy of the project and configure deployment to synchronize with the remote.

Comment: Let me try this out.
Thanks a lot.